# How to reinstall drivers from usb boot in windows 10

Tags: windows-10, boot, drivers

I currently have a boot problem in windows10 which I assume is due to faulty drivers. How can I uninstall and re-install these drivers from a usb boot? Which software would I need?

Comment: Are you talking about installing it within Safe Mode or WinRE?  I ask because you cannot install software within the WinRE environment.  If you suspect a bad driver, modify the registry hive, and disable the key that loads the driver and delete the suspect .inf file

Comment: I'm thinking about using something like Hiren's BootCD.

Comment: Hiren is WinPE, which is a variation of WinRE, which of course you can't install Windows applications within.  You can install applications to WinPE, or specifically add them to the image so you can use them, but you can't install/remove existing applications from your installation.

Answer (score 1):

You can list drivers of Windows 7-10 installed in D:\ using

```
Dism /Image:D:\ /Get-Drivers
```

Remove driver oem1.inf for example with:

```
Dism /Image:D:\ /Remove-Driver /Driver:oem1.inf
```

Add driver with:

```
Dism /Image:D:\ /Add-Driver /Driver:<path to inf file>
```

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a iastorafs.sys missing or corrupted issue
0xc0000098

This was after I installed the latest Intel rst optane setup file product version 18.7.6.1010.2, file version 18.1.0.35, on a computer acting as a server (built 2019) , in raid mirror configuration
Mobo: gigabyte z390 gaming x

I scour the internet looking for a solution but nothing works..

Cant even get into any safe modes at all in boot up, they all throw the same error.

With a bit of meddling here and there,

I downloaded an older version from a random site by first looking for the version to download from the motherboard site (the mobo site does not have the unpacked files, which I couldn’t extract and copy)

Here’s what I did in order and somehow I fixed it. And the Intel optane software installed and works too apparently…

1)
Boot into WinPE using hbcd
Located the two files
Iastorafs.sys
And
Iastorac.sys
In c:\windows\system32\drivers
Renamed them and replace them with the file from the downloaded copy

- rebooted - didn’t work

2. 

Went back into WinPE and installed all drivers (not sure if this did anything because it appears that it is not related to the actual operating system when I do that ) because WinPE runs on a virtual os

- not sure if it work since I followed on with the next two steps

3. 

Located the repository in
C:\windows\system32\driverstore\filerepository\iastorac.inf_amd64_ac65d2d2fx98d80ce

(The last bit is probably random and different for everyone)

1 - Make a copy and renamed it - copy

2 - Copied the downloaded old version and dump it in here

3 - as an added extra measure, dump the 2 .sys files in c:\windows\system32

(I did this because in the past some drivers were searching for files in that folder instead of the driver folders , so no idea if this did anything either )

My last resort was to attempt to kill the mirror and run the hdd as achi (thank god I didn’t need to do this step)

4- reboot and bingo it suddenly just loaded windows…

Good luck to anyone else who encounters this problem

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1242220)